# Result of Stream.Read if no bytes are available within ReadTimeout but will be soon?

Tags: c#, stream, timeout

I have to create a readable stream. Due to access to external sources the stream is fairly slowly filled with data. To save memory, I want users of the stream to read data as soon as possible.

**Question: What should Stream.Read return if no byte is available right now but will be soon?**

[MSDN about Stream.Read](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.read(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Implementations return the number of bytes read. The implementation
>   will block until at least one byte of data can be read, in the event
>   that no data is available. Read returns 0 only when there is no more
>   data in the stream and no more is expected. An implementation is free
>   to return fewer bytes than requested even if the end of the stream has
>   not been reached.

Alas, the description does not say anything about the ReadTimeout.

[MSDN about Stream.ReadTimeout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.readtimeout%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

> Gets or sets a value, in miliseconds, that determines how long the
>   stream will attempt to read before timing out. The ReadTimeout
>   property should be overridden to provide the appropriate behavior for
>   the stream.

Okay, so Reading is clear, isn't it?

- If there are more bytes available then requested, return the requested bytes.
- If more bytes are requested than are currently available, return all available bytes, with a return value indicating the number of returned bytes.
- If no byte is available right now, but the end of the stream is not reached yet, then apparently some bytes will be available in the future. In that case, the function should  **wait maximum ReadTimeout for any byte to become available** and return all available bytes as soon as any byte becomes available, with a maximum of the requested number of bytes.
- If and only if no bytes are available, and no bytes will become available because the end of the stream is reached, the return value will be 0.

But what to do if the end of the stream is not reached and no byte becomes available within ReadTimeout?

I can't return 0, because that would mean that the end of the stream is reached.

Should I raise a `TimeOutException`, although `Stream.Read` does not mention it?

**What is the standard reaction of Stream.Read return if no byte is available withing ReadTimeout but the end of the stream has not been reached?**

Comment: An exception seems perfectly reasonable to me, NetworkStream for example throws an IOException on timeout.

Comment: What kind of Stream? Stream is abstract. It depends on the actual implementation. A [NetworkStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bk6w7hs8(v=vs.110).aspx) has InfiniteTimeout as default, for example.

Comment: What kind of stream: I have to create a class derived from Stream that provides data gathered from various sources. Users should not notice the difference between reading from a FileStream, a stream that reads from a service, my stream, or any other stream. Hence I want the same reaction as every stream that uses ReadTimeout

Comment: Well read() blocks & returns 0 or a count, as you cant do either the only avenue left is to throw.

Comment: "Hence I want the same reaction as every stream that uses ReadTimeout" - that is an impossible guarantee, since anyone can create such a stream and raise completely random custom exceptions on timeout. The best you should aim for is: sensible. Which would mean (IMO) ether `IOException` or `TimeoutException`

Comment: Then you have to establish you own way to determine a Read Timeout, and override the Stream [CanTimeout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.cantimeout(v=vs.110).aspx) property. Each Stream implementation has its own way to determine a timeout. NetworkStream times out if a Newtwork is not available. So you also have to override ReadTimeout.

Comment: But what options do you have? You cannot return 0 so all you can do is throwing exception.

Comment: @Evk And a custom event, that a consumer of this class can subscribe?

Comment: @Jimi but while you raise that event, what `Read` should do? Stuck forever?

Comment: @Evk I meant, since you have to create a common logic (for all the stream types you have to handle) that governs the ReadTimeout, this class defines what a ReadTimeout is and its value, handles the IOException (equal for each stream type) and raises an event that a consumer can subscribe.

Comment: From several comments I understand that various streams might react differently. Can I conclude that the definition of the base class function Stream.Read is fairly undefined?

Comment: Well, a stream is a sequence of bytes. An abstraction of it. You could have `Stream stream = New FileStream()` or `Stream stream = httpResponse.GetResponseStream()`. The abstraction lets you read that sequence of bytes indifferently. As the source was the same. I think that's pretty much the most solid thing you have. However different streams behave differently in relation to a Timeout. Because their source can determine this behaviour. But you can override this behaviour and define a common one. Starting from the differences. The Timeout is one of them. Define and apply your own logic there.

Comment: Of course you are right that a derived class can do whatever it wants within a derived function. But I'd say that in a properly derived class the pre- and post-condition of the overridden functions should equal those of the base functions, otherwise users who don't really know that the class is a derived class see different behaviour.

Comment: And I agree. The Stream class evens most of it out, because the abstraction itself acts as an equaliizer. But the (few) differences must have a common ground. Otherwise, why a custom class? The Timeout is, imo, a good example. You could have a property that lets the class user define a Timeout (no matter how the **implemented** class - `NetworkStream`, `Filestream` etc. treats it). If the class consumer does not define one, implement and manage a logic the is in the scope of the custom class you're building (what this class is for and how it should work, you're the only one who knows it).